# url not working after hosting the webpage in firebase

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am developing a pwa app with firebase. If I run my page in local machine using a firebase serve command, it is working perfectly. But after deploy the webpage in firebase hosting only the index.html page is working. If I access the other pages it ill give 404 page not found error. Please give the solution for my problem..

My webpage link is https://attendance-system-51d55.firebaseapp.com/

(login,signup pages are not working)

Comment: Are the other pages in the same directory as the *index.html*?

Comment: yes. all other pages are same directory

Comment: Do your files by chance have capital letters in them? Firebase Hosting runs on a case-sensitive filesystem, whereas Mac OS and (maybe) Windows do not. Please make sure your case matches exactly for the files.

Comment: Thanks Michael Bleign. its Working

Comment: How did you solve your issue?